# getting length of each element of a list from user input

Tags: python

I am trying to implement this code, I have a list of string, `secret_word = [“the”,”blue”,”house”]`
When the user pick the word, `user_pick = input(“Pick the secret word: ”)`, if it is in the `secret_word` list, I will append to the new list, `right_words = []` . If they want a clue for the word, It will print the number of letters of that word. Problem is that, I couldn’t get the number of letters of a specific string. For example: if the user picked : `“the”` correctly but ask for clue for the second word, how can I give the number of letters of the 2nd word. In this case, “blue”. Same way, if the user picked `"blue"` correctly and ask for clue for the 3rd one - the clue should print 5 for `"house"`

```
secret_word = ["the","blue","house"]
right_words = []
user_pick = input("Pick the secret word: ")
if user_pick in secret_word:
      right_words.append(user_pick)
if secret_word not in right_words:
      print("clue", "the number of letters in this word", len(right_words))
```

I get the 1 as a clue which is the length of the list after picking `"the"`, but I need 4 letters for `"blue"` (if the user already selected "the" correctly), if the user picked, "blue" correctly, then 5 letters for `"house"` as a clue.
I really have no clue how I can make this code work! Kindly help please :) If anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a counter `c` that holds the number of correct guesses so far.
Then print out `len(secret_word[c])`.

Note that `if user_pick in secret_word` is probably semantically incorrect because it let's your user guess the elements of `secret_word` in any order.

Comment: Ohh It worked !!! Thank you. I was struggling with it whole day. Would you kindly explain it please :) ? how it works? indexing? @timgeb

Answer (score 1):

Another version.  The key is using a counter as you now know...then iterating over it.  Count is by index so

```
while counter <=2
```

is actually 3 positions, 0,1,2 which matches the length of the secret_word list

```
secret_word = ["the","blue","house"]
right_words = []

counter = 0

while counter <=2:
    user_pick = input("Pick the secret word: ")
    if user_pick == secret_word[counter]:
          right_words.append(user_pick)


    if user_pick != secret_word[counter]:
          print("clue", "the number of letters in this word:", len(secret_word[counter]))
          counter -= 1

    if len(right_words) == len(secret_word):
        break
    counter += 1

print(right_words)


Pick the secret word: the
Pick the secret word: wrong
clue the number of letters in this word: 4
Pick the secret word: blue
Pick the secret word: wrong
clue the number of letters in this word: 5
Pick the secret word: wrong
clue the number of letters in this word: 5
Pick the secret word: house
['the', 'blue', 'house']
```

Other note:  you need to move the user input into the loop (so it repeats itself)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
secret_words = ["the", "blue", "horse"]  # Yur secret words list


# Creating function that takes one parameter: word_index
def get_length_of_word(word_index):
    global secret_words  # Globalizing the variable
    # If the following statement is difficult to understand, let me break it down for you
    return len(secret_words[word_index])

    '''
    Lets assume word_index = 1
    The statement: secret_words[word_index] will use the 1st item in our list (the list starts from 0)
    In our case, the first item is 'blue' (not 'the', that is acually the 0th item)
    The len() statement then takes the length of the string
    Since it returns the value, you can assign it to a variable and use it later on
    '''


print(get_length_of_word(1)) # Printing the length of the first word in our list ('blue').

# You could assign to a variable, with something like: 
# length_of_second_word = get_length_of_word(1)
```

Comment: Note that this is just for getting the length of a word, not your entire program

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
secret_word = ["the","blue","house"]
right_words = []

while len(secret_word) != 0:  #a while loop so the user can have a few tries, the loop stops when the user guessed all of the words correctly
    user_pick = input("Pick the secret word: ")
    if user_pick in secret_word:
        right_words.append(user_pick)
        secret_word.remove(user_pick) #avoid a user picking the same word twice
    else:
        clue_input = input("Do you want a clue? y/n \n") #ask the user if they want a clue
        if clue_input == 'y': #only runs in the case of 'y', so the user can just press enter for no
            clue_word = random.choice(secret_word) #pick a random word from the secret words
            print("Number of letters in a word: " + str(len(clue_word))) #print the length of that word to the user
```